# Bad UV and ways to improve it

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

Smart UV project gave me this mess:
[image]

Is there a proper way to unrwap it without making seams manually? Some methods or programs to reduce the number of islands?

Comment: Hello :). Can't post a full answer now, but the Blender manual has a [page on Smart UV project options.](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/uv/unwrapping/mapping_types.html#smart-uv-project) I'm sure you'll find what you need there.

Comment: how do you want to work afterwards? Please give more explanations...